# GWT Super Dev Mode : Working with Multiple Projects / Inherits

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

**My Project Structure**

**Core Project** (it has separate module .xml file) 
     **CoreProject.gwt.xml (it will not have any entry point defined)**

it has abstract entry point class And this core project is used in

**Project A** 
(It inherits Core Project in module .xml file. And this has the entry point class)
     **ProjectA.gwt.xml
               
And ProjectA EntryPoint extends Abstract CoreProject EntryPoint Class directly.**

So when I try to run "Project A" as java application for super dev mode (I added Core Project in classpath and source tabs of Run Configuration)

and my program arguments is

like

**-src src/ com.xxx.CoreProject com.xxxx.ProjectA**

So the output is, **It compiles the CoreProject Successfully. But when it comes to "ProjectA". it throws error.**

Error in ProjectA entrypoint class. Not able to find source for CoreProject Entry Point. 
Did you forgot to inherit the module.

My Working Env:
**Eclipse Kepler.**

.... Example Code .....

CoreProject.gwt.xml

```
<module rename-to='CoreProject'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->

    <inherits name="com.xxxxxx.AppsCommonNoTheme" />
    <!-- inherits name="com.smartgwt.SmartGwtNoScript"/ -->
    <inherits name="com.smartgwt.tools.SmartGwtTools" />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />
    <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>

    <script src='scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js' />
    <script src='scripts/strophe.js' />
    <script src='scripts/bwboshconnector.js' />

    <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
</module>
```

CoreProject Entry Point Class

```
public abstract class CoreProject implements EntryPoint {

// abstractMethods 

public void onModuleLoad() {
  // Code to Call those abstract Methods.

}

}
```

ProjectA gwt xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="ProjectA">

  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name="com.xxxx.CoreProject" />

  <entry-point class='com.xxxxx.ProjectA ' />
    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code  -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" />
    <set-configuration-property name='xsiframe.failIfScriptTag' value='FALSE'/>
    <add-linker name="xsiframe" />
</module>
```

Project A Entry Point

```
public class ProjectA extends CoreProject {

/// Implemented Logic for those abstract methods.
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit your question, and include the significant code of your gwt.xml files and entrypoints (namespaces, inheritance, etc.)

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Are you trying to debug the SmartGWT stuff?

Comment: Try to compile your project first before running in SDM. GWT compiler may show you more information about where your mistake is.

Comment: I'm using kepler and I'm not trying to debus smartgwt. I just want to test code which we have written. Gwt compile works fine. I'm able run the application in normal mode without any issues. even building war works fine.